# ¿Cómo puedo consultar en MySQL, solo las columnas que tienen al menos 1 registro?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una base de datos en MySQL que tiene como 100 campos y mas de 100 mil registros.
Y no todos los 100 campos son llenados.
Cómo puedo consultar solo las columnas que tienen al menos 1 registro?

Por ejemplo si tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y deseo que la consulta me retorne la información, pero sin la Column3 ya que esta no tiene información. Claro, esto tomando en cuenta que por los 100 mil registros no se cual es la columna que no tiene datos.

El resultado seria algo como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, hay alguna manera posible de crear una query que me permita hacer consultas, pero que no retorne las columnas que no tienen datos.
Como mencionaba anteriormente, esto tomando en cuenta que tienes una tabla con 300 campos y en la tabla hay mas de 100 mil registros, y se te hace imposible identificar los campos que no tienen información. ¿Cuál seria la mejor opción para omitir esta columna vacía en el query?

Comment: Si tienes MySQL ver >= 8.0.23 podría ser una opción hacer invisible la columna:  `ALTER TABLE tabla ALTER COLUMN Column3 SET INVISIBLE`.

Comment: Seria una buena opción si puedo identificar la columna que no tiene datos. 
Pero como decía en la explicación de lo solicitado, tomar en cuenta que son mas de 300 campos y 100 mil registros. Entonces no puedo ponerme a buscar que campo es el que no tiene datos, porque tomaría un tiempo largo. 
Por el momento no me es viable esta respuesta. Pero muchas gracias por el intento.

Comment: Las opciones para columnas dinámicas en SQL son escasas y muy limitadas. Si pretendes revisar valores nulos en **toda** la tabla cada vez que hagas una consulta eso será sumamente ineficiente. Por otro lado ¿Para qué mantener columnas que ni usas ni quieres ver y ni sabes cuáles son?; si se justificara el caso, puedes -después de todo- ignorar lo que quieras en el front-end.